# Concurrent loads and stores

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, system, theory

In C I have:

```
double balance;
void deposit(double amount) 
{balance = balance +amount;}
```

machine language:

```
load R1, balance
load R2, amount
add R1, R2
store R1, balance
```

If the variable balance contains 500 and two threads run the procedure to deposit 300 and 200 respectively concurrently, how can this be problematic? And how do I use a concurrency mechanism to make this procedure thread safe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concurrency 101

```
Thread 1                  Thread 2

load R1, balance
load R2, amount           load R1, balance
add R1, R2                load R2, amount
store R1, balance         add R1, R2
                          store R1, balance
```

The write by Thread 1 is lost.  (There are many sequences that achieve approximately the same result.)

You fix it by locking `balance` so that only one thread or the other has access to it between the load and the store.  Acquire a mutex on `balance` at the start of the sequence and release it at the end. Consider loading `amount` before loading `balance` to reduce the scope of the mutex to the minimum.